# Invoice pricing changes based on user input

Tags: c#, menu, invoice

This is my invoice for a garage calculator where it allows the user to input the dimension/paint/trim. My problem is at the invoice, I don't know how to change the pricing depending on the chosen paint/trim.

```
if (trimPrice == 1 || trimPrice == 2 || trimPrice == 3) {
 if (paintPrice == 1 || paintPrice == 2 || paintPrice == 3) {
  Console.WriteLine("Siding Invoice");
  Console.WriteLine("==================");
  Console.WriteLine(gSide1 + "   Siding Boxes  " + " @" + paintPrice + "=  " + "{0:C}", gTotal1);
  Console.WriteLine(tgTotal2 + "  Trim pieces " + "    @" + trimPrice + "=  " + "{0:C}", tgCost);
  Console.WriteLine("                   Net Total    =  " + ("{0:C}"), nTotal);
  Console.WriteLine("                   GST          =  " + ("{0:C}"), GST);
  Console.WriteLine("                   Delivery Fee =  $250.00");
  Console.WriteLine("                   Total        =  " + ("{0:C}"), Total);
  Console.WriteLine("Press Y to Redo");
  Console.Write("Option ");
 }
}
```

Trim Colour/Price

White $28.35

Blue $41.65

Red $49.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You need to recalculate your values. For example,

```
 if (trimPrice >=1 && trimPrice <= 3 && paintPrice>=1 && paintPrice<=3)
 {

        gTotal1 =  // Your logic here for gTotal1
        tgCost = // Your logic here for tgCost
        nTotal = // Your logic here for nTotal
        GST = // Your logic here for GST
        Total = // Your logic here for Total 
        Console.WriteLine("Siding Invoice");
        Console.WriteLine("==================");
        Console.WriteLine(gSide1 + "   Siding Boxes  " + " @" + paintPrice + "=  " + "{0:C}", gTotal1);
        Console.WriteLine(tgTotal2 + "  Trim pieces " + "    @" + trimPrice + "=  " + "{0:C}", tgCost);
        Console.WriteLine("                   Net Total    =  " + ("{0:C}"), nTotal);
        Console.WriteLine("                   GST          =  " + ("{0:C}"), GST);
        Console.WriteLine("                   Delivery Fee =  $250.00");
        Console.WriteLine("                   Total        =  " + ("{0:C}"), Total);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Y to Redo");
        Console.Write("Option ");

    }
```

You can retain a dictionary of prices for Paint and Trim. For example,

```
var dictionaryPaint = new Dictionary<int,int>
            {
                [1] = 100,
                [2] = 200,
                [3] = 300,
            };
```

I have used numerics for paint here as it was in OP, but a better solution would be to use Enums. Once the dictionary of price is declared, you can use the following.

```
gTotal1 = dictionaryPaint[1] * 12; //12 is just an example. You can use your logic here.
```

Complete Code

```
var dictionaryPaint = new Dictionary<int,int>
{
    [1] = 100,
    [2] = 200,
    [3] = 300,
};

var dictionaryTrim = new Dictionary<string,int>
{
   [1] = 110,
   [2] = 210,
   [3] = 310,
};
if (trimPrice >=1 && trimPrice <= 3 && paintPrice>=1 && paintPrice<=3)
{

            gTotal1 = dictionaryPaint[1] * 12;  // Your logic here for gTotal1
            tgCost = // Your logic here for tgCost
            nTotal = // Your logic here for nTotal
            GST = // Your logic here for GST
            Total = // Your logic here for Total 
            Console.WriteLine("Siding Invoice");
            Console.WriteLine("==================");
            Console.WriteLine(gSide1 + "   Siding Boxes  " + " @" + paintPrice + "=  " + "{0:C}", gTotal1);
            Console.WriteLine(tgTotal2 + "  Trim pieces " + "    @" + trimPrice + "=  " + "{0:C}", tgCost);
            Console.WriteLine("                   Net Total    =  " + ("{0:C}"), nTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("                   GST          =  " + ("{0:C}"), GST);
            Console.WriteLine("                   Delivery Fee =  $250.00");
            Console.WriteLine("                   Total        =  " + ("{0:C}"), Total);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Y to Redo");
            Console.Write("Option ");




}
```

Btw, please note you can replace

```
if (trimPrice == 1 || trimPrice == 2 || trimPrice == 3) {
 if (paintPrice == 1 || paintPrice == 2 || paintPrice == 3) {
```

With

```
 if (trimPrice >=1 && trimPrice <= 3 && paintPrice>=1 && paintPrice<=3)
```

Comment: Yes I need to recalculate the total cost of the inputted paint/trim. For example there are three paint they can choose from (White,Red and Blue) and the cost is different for each. Once they choose one the total cost will change base on what they chose

Comment: So, you can calculate them based on Paint Price. For example, Total could be Total = Paint Price * AreaToPaint

Comment: But then what about the other two options of paint? because if they select one of the  three colours then the total cost changes.

Comment: @SH093 I think i understood your issue better now. please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your prices do not change while your application is running, you can create a static [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) to store prices against trim type or paint type identifiers.

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, int> TrimPrices = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    { 1, 100 },
    { 2, 200 },
    { 3, 500 }
};
```

You can then access, and print the price of the selected trim like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(TrimPrices[trimPrice]);
```

Comment: The pricing for each paint/trim is different. My problem is the total end cost of what was chosen by the customer.